# node - package.json: how to execute script which sets environment variables

Tags: node.js

I'd like inside my package.json execute some script which will set environment variables that my app could use.
I need something like this (in my package.json)

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "set-env-vars.sh && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline & cd server && NODE_ENV=development node app.js",
  },
```

This is my set-env-vars.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ENV_MONGODB_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
...
```

I know that I need use source or . to export my variables into shell, this is working in shell, but not for my package.json dev-script.

Any solutions to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in single ampersand (&) after *webpack-dev-server* invocation. Trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background. In practice, your command will be split into 2 parts, which are going to be invoked in separate shells asynchronously. If you use ampersand (&) intentionally, then you should source env vars in both parts like this:

```
. ./set-env-vars.sh && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline & . ./set-env-vars.sh && cd server && NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

so, variables from *set-env-vars.sh* will be available for both *webpack-dev-server* and *node*

Or if you want to run it synchronously:

```
. ./set-env-vars.sh && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline && cd server && NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

Comment: The problem is that when I add `.` or `source` inside script, I have receive this:

`sh: line 0: .: set-env-vars.sh: file not found`

Comment: I think you should use `./set-env-vars.sh` instead of `set-env-vars.sh` to execute file from current directory.

Comment: So finally this is works:
`webpack-dev-server --hot --inline & . ./set-env-vars.sh && cd server && NODE_ENV=development node app.js`
Thank you! )